# Why is みんな sometimes used with a particle and without?

Tags: particles

I've seen in Genki I みんな used without a particle (no particle follows the word). For example:

> たいていみんな寝ています
>
> 私のかぞくは四人です。みんなとてもしんせつです。

However, I've also seen sentences in which it is followed by a particle:

> あなたがみんな**を**救った
>
> みんな**が**日本に興味をもっている

Using it with a particle makes sense to me, since I translate it as everyone. Why is it sometimes followed by a particle and sometimes not?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9777/9831

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is みんな being used as a "counter"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9777/is-%e3%81%bf%e3%82%93%e3%81%aa-being-used-as-a-counter)

Answer (score 1):

From the chat, by @Chocolate:

> たいていみんな寝ています -- here みんな is an adverb. the subject is omitted
>   "They are all asleep"
>
> みんなとてもしんせつです。 here again みんな is an adverb. No particle
>   required. The subject is 家族 
>   "They are all kind."

Another example:

> みんなが出かけたあと、～～ -- After everyone left, ~~
>
> here みんな is a noun
>
> 家族がみんな出かけたあと、～～ -- After my family all left (or, everyone of my family
>   left)
>
> here みんな is an adverb

A few more similar words (which work both as nouns and adverbs):

- 全部
- 全員
- すべて

Answer (score 0):

Not only can particles be omitted sometimes, especially in colloquial speech, みんな can also be an adverb as well as a noun.

For example:

> 私の家族はみんな音楽が得意です。
>
> Everyone in my family is good with music.
>
> 人はみんな違う。
>
> All people are different.

Comment: Thanks for anwsering. I understand the general reasons you give, but why would there be no particle in the examples I mentioned? They are not colloquial speech and I can't see how "minna" could be an adverb in them.

Comment: The difference between the meaning of everyone and all.