# Word order in 銀河鉄道の夜

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

I was reading 銀河鉄道の夜, and I’m confused on the choice of word order in the following sentence. I understand what the sentence means, but I do not understand why みんな isnt before が.

> たしかにあれがみんな星だと

Let me know if more context is necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9777/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70479/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarity, in the context of the 銀河鉄道の夜 the clause the question is about is meant as an answer to

> [...]このぼんやりと白いものがほんとうは何かご承知ですか。

— something the teacher asks the class while pointing to an illustration of the Milky Way, and it is part of a longer sentence that continues on like so:

> たしかにあれがみんな星だと、いつか雑誌で読んだのでしたが...

With that out of the way, the reason みんな comes after が here is because it is used as an adverb (meaning "all, everything, wholly") rather than a noun.

> たしかにあれが**みんな**星だと　*...that (it is/they are) certainly **all** stars*

みんな as a noun could not really have been used here, as would then refer to a group of people, while the sentence is about what the Milky Way is composed of.

This use corresponds to its second definition on [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%BF%E3%82%93%E3%81%82) as well as on [goo.ne.jp](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%9A%86_%28%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AA%29/) (here listed under みな). Those two sites also give the following examples, respectively:

> 木の葉は**みんな**落ちてしまった。The leaves have all fallen.
> 今回の不始末は**みんな**私の責任です　This (case of) mismanagement is entirely my fault. (emphasis, second translation mine)

As adverbs cannot take the subject-marker が, the only way for this みんな to end up before it would be by being placed before あれが, but while (as neither a native speaker nor an advanced learner) I may be wrong on this and cannot properly explain it, to me it sounds incredibly weird and is most likely just incorrect.

Comment: Come to think of it, I am not sure if the "everyone" use of みんな wouldn't be more properly classified as a pronoun rather than a noun... I feel the distinction isn't particularly important for this answer, but if someone with more experience finds it more appropriate please feel free to edit.